# reshape a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, lreshape

suppose a dataframe like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'A1', 'B1'])
```

[image]

I would like to have a dataframe which looks like:

[image]

what does not work:

```
new_rows = int(df.shape[1]/2) * df.shape[0]
new_cols = 2
df.values.reshape(new_rows, new_cols, order='F')
```

of course I could loop over the data and make a new list of list but there must be a better way. Any ideas ?

Comment: I added a more robust answer that generalizes to the nearly the exact situation you have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `pd.wide_to_long` function is built almost exactly for this situation, where you have many of the same variable prefixes that end in a different digit suffix. The only difference here is that your first set of variables don't have a suffix, so you will need to rename your columns first.

The only issue with `pd.wide_to_long` is that it must have an identification variable, `i`, unlike `melt`. `reset_index` is used to create a this uniquely identifying column, which is dropped later. I think this might get corrected in the future.

```
df1 = df.rename(columns={'A':'A1', 'B':'B1', 'A1':'A2', 'B1':'B2'}).reset_index()
pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i='index', j='id')\
  .reset_index()[['A', 'B', 'id']]

    A   B id
0   1   2  1
1   5   6  1
2   9  10  1
3   3   4  2
4   7   8  2
5  11  12  2
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857), for column `id` [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
a = [col for col in df.columns if 'A' in col]
b = [col for col in df.columns if 'B' in col]
df1 = pd.lreshape(df, {'A' : a, 'B' : b})

df1['id'] = np.repeat(np.arange(len(df.columns) // 2), len (df.index))  + 1
print (df1)
    A   B  id
0   1   2   1
1   5   6   1
2   9  10   1
3   3   4   2
4   7   8   2
5  11  12   2
```

EDIT:

[`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) is currently undocumented, but it is possible it might be removed([with pd.wide_to_long too](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271)).

Possible solution is merging all 3 functions to one - maybe `melt`, but now it is not implementated. Maybe in some new version of pandas. Then my answer will be updated.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this in 3 steps:

1. Make a new dataframe `df2` holding only the data you want to be added to the initial dataframe `df`.
2. Delete the data from `df` that will be added below (and that was used to make `df2`.
3. Append `df2` to `df`.

Like so:

```
# step 1: create new dataframe
df2 = df[['A1', 'B1']]
df2.columns = ['A', 'B']

# step 2: delete that data from original
df = df.drop(["A1", "B1"], 1)

# step 3: append
df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Note how when you do `df.append()` you need to specify `ignore_index=True` so the new columns get appended to the index rather than keep their old index.

Your end result should be your original dataframe with the data rearranged like you wanted:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
    A   B
0   1   2
1   5   6
2   9  10
3   3   4
4   7   8
5  11  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat()` like so:

```
#Split into separate tables
df_1 = df[['A', 'B']]
df_2 = df[['A1', 'B1']]
df_2.columns = ['A', 'B'] # Make column names line up

# Add the ID column
df_1 = df_1.assign(id=1)
df_2 = df_2.assign(id=2)

# Concatenate
pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
```

Comment: @Moritz - I see. Personally I'd just do that in a for loop. Though perhaps @jezrael's ``lreshape`` solution is better for that case.