# pandas - make multiple rows for each column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert some data into a more useful format from .xls to .csv with pandas.

I have loaded the data like so:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('file.xls')
```

which returns a data frame which looks like:

```
Name    Event1    Date1    Event2    Date2    Event3    Date3
Joe     jump      1.1.13   skip      1.2.13   hop       1.3.14
Jack    skip      1.2.12   run       1.5.14   NA        NA
```

I would like to reformat the data so names are repeated multiple times for each event they participated in with their date. i.e.

```
Name    Event   Date
Joe     jump    1.1.13
Joe     skip    1.2.13
```

In a way I can remove all NA. I have multiple sheets in xcel which is why i want to concatenate everything in this way.

Is there a simple command or am I stuck with for loops?

thanks!

Comment: Look into `pandas.melt`.

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928911/reshape-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L820) which is the go to method for converting a wide formatted `DF` to a long one such as this.

This method accepts a dictionary as it's groups parameter wherein the column names starting with a certain prefix are clustered under a single wholesome column.

```
d = dict(Event=df.filter(regex="^Event").columns, Date=df.filter(regex="^Date").columns)
pd.lreshape(df, d)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one.  You could also use `dict(Event=df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Event')], Date=df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Date')])`.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to keep things concise ;-)

Comment: I could not find the documentation other than in the code on github:https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857 ; is this function too new ?

Comment: Yeah, that's because it isn't a publicly documented method and still very much in it's experimental stages. There have been [speculations](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003) going on whether to use `pd.lreshape` or it's sister method `pd.wide_to_long`. Again, if the grouping variables aren't of the same length, then there are chances of it giving out erroneous results.