# how to reshape the csv file with 2118 row and 22 colums into 4 4 dimension

Tags: python-2.7, file, csv

I want to reshape the CSV row and columns into 4 dimension form that is acceptable for CNN in python.

Rows are 2118 and columns are 22

Comment: Use pandas. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42928911/4015990

Answer (score 0):

You first need to figure out the size of each dimension. After that you can use `numpy.reshape`.

For example we can convert a `2118x22` array into a `2118x22x1x1` array which satisfies the `4 dimensions` requirement like:

```
original_array = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2118, 22))
dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4 = 2118, 22, 1, 1
original_array.reshape((dim1, dim2 , dim3, dim4))
```

Now your task is figure out the numbers for `dim1`, `dim2`, `dim3` and `dim4`.